# Can I hide events on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I use my Google Calendar for my homework schedule, as most of my professors use Google Calendar and you can click a button to have their events integrate with your calendar.

If I finish an event (homework assignment, studying for test, etc), I want to be able to make it grey-ish, kinda like this:

[image: past events]

I would prefer to do this without deleting it (from my calendar, I have no control over the professor's calendar) would also work.

I thought about using:

[image]

Then going to *More details*. However, that only shows:

[image: this].

Comment: google calendar does not have a feature to hide events

Comment: that would be a nice feature, but not supported

Comment: While it won't help you if you complete your homework before it's due, there is a setting under "General" to "Dim past events".

Comment: Many users want this feature as well - you can vote for it on [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/W8jpiJZ_2Gs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do any change if the calendar is in 'Other Calendars' and read only (looks like it is from your screenshot). In such situation I use right click on the event and 'copy to my calendar' link which creates duplicate of event in my calendar of choice. Then I change color and add e.g. 'DONE' keyword. It is not ideal workaround but at least I can visually distinguish between TODO and finished items.

Other option (especially in case the schedule is stable) would be to import calendar from iCal or CSV instead of adding it to 'Other Calendars'. If imported, the calendar belongs to you and you can change individual item properties/delete or move items.

Comment: Hmm it's funny that until now google hasn't implement this feature. What I can do now is just delete the event, because it distract me to my focus. But If I want to know the history of past events, it will be burden...

Answer (score 4):

Hiding an event is another, obvious feature that is missing from Google Calendar.
But you could change the background color for that event to a color which indicates, to you, the event is not active.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an iPhone, you can use Pod to hide any event on your calendar: https://pod.io/blog/hiding.html

Comment: This quesstion is about Google Calendar, not iPhone calendar, so this answer is unrelated.